# sem_post sem_wait functions in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, semaphore

I want to edit sem_post() and sem_wait() functions in my linux (ubuntu distro). However I cannot find the location of the functions. I assumed it is on semaphore.c on kernel but I could not find. My linux is x86 environment 3.2.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit/find those functions' source codes, they are pre-compiled in the pthread library.